# Use cases of the BitSet over List, Set

Tags: java, list, set, bitset

What are the use cases when the BitSet should be preferable over the Set and List? Besides, does it have any kind of performance implication?

At least, I would like to know the best use cases for the BitSet and when I need to use them in the production code irrespective of the other data-structure mentioned in the question.

Comment: How on earth can a Set or List replace a what a `BitSet` is meant to represent?

Comment: I see some code where BitSet is keeping the indexes and wonder why someone would prefer that over the Set or List which can do the same?

Comment: It could be the case when you need a fast and memory-efficient data structure, for example, [Bloom filter](https://gvnix.medium.com/bloom-filters-in-action-ea7304463fc6).

Comment: @IlyaLapitan would you please write an answer with all the knowledge that you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**General use case:** do a search if value *V* is present in dataset *DS*.

**Special use case:** there is an organization with dataset *DS* of employees' emails stored in the database. You want to implement a solution to verify when a new employee account is creating there is no such email *V* already present in the database *DS*. Ideally, you want to avoid additional calls to DB. The total number of employees in the organization is 2 200 000 (Walmart had it in 2019 based on statistical data available).

**Theory:** to avoid additional calls to DB you can put all existing emails from DB into some *collection* and search if email already present in the DB against this *collection*. If we speak about *List* and *Set*, they both **store at least data elements** by themselves with possible additional overhead based on backed data structure, for example, *LinkedList* will need memory overhead for pointers. There is a real chance we don't have enough memory to put all these data in our collection.

Now, time to talk about the Bloom filter. The Bloom Filter is a fast and memory-efficient probabilistic data structure. Probabilistic data structures provide memory-efficient solutions with a tradeoff of providing a ‘probable’ result instead of a ‘guaranteed’ one (discussed above). A Bloom filter with 1% error and an optimal number of hash functions (extremely fast hash functions) requires only about 9.6 bits per element, regardless of the size of the elements. A Bloom filter **doesn’t store the data elements** by itself.

There are 2 main components in the Bloom filter:

- bite array (in Java can be represented using *java.util.BitSet* class)
- hash function (one or more)

There are 2 operations in the Bloom filter:

- **insert**

  1. Value *V* is hashed by *K* hash functions generating *K* different indices.
  2. The values against these indices are marked as 1 (true).

     ```java
     //see more details about actual implementation by the link below
     BloomFilter bf = new BloomFilter(0.1, 10); 
     //BitSet {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
     bf.add("tim.brand@organization.com");
     //BitSet {0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0}
     bf.add("angel.born1@organization.com");
     //BitSet {0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1}
     bf.add("casey.clous@organization.com");
     //BitSet {1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0}
     ```
- **search**

  1. Value *V* is hashed by *K* hash functions generating *K* different indices.
  2. The values against these indices are checked if all of them are 1 then there is a strong possibility of having this data in the dataset *DS* (needed call to DB). If any of them is zero then we definitely don’t have this value present in the dataset *DS* (no call to DB is needed).

**Findings:**
So, in this particular case *BloomFilter* based on *BitSet* seems more efficient than *Set* or *List*.

**Links:**

- [Book: Java Coding Problems by Anghel Leonard (128. Bloom filter)](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-coding-problems/9781789801415/)
- [Bloom Filter implementation in Java](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Java-Coding-Problems/tree/master/Chapter05/P128_BloomFilter)
- [Bloom Filters in Action](https://gvnix.medium.com/bloom-filters-in-action-ea7304463fc6)
- [Probabilistic Data structures: Bloom filter](https://hackernoon.com/probabilistic-data-structures-bloom-filter-5374112a7832)

**Note:** there are requirements for has functions used and Bloom filter parameters tuning but they are out of the scope of this question.